# ¿Como saber si el primer caracter de un String es un int?

Tags: java

Mi problema como el título lo indica deseo saber si el primer caracter de un String es un número 9. Tengo el siguiente código pero quiero saber si se puede optimizar:

```
String palabra = "9394";
if(palabra != null && palabra.contains("9")){
    int index = palabra.indexOf("9");
    if(index == 0){
         System.out.println("9 es la primera letra");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `string.charAt(0)` que te permite obtener el primer carácter del string.

```
if (string.charAt(0) = '9') {
// Tu codigo
}
```

> `.charAt(index)` Recordar que devuelve un tipo char.

---

**Información Adicional**: si quieres saber si el primer carácter es un dígito, no importa cual (no solo 0 a 9, todos los del unicode):

```
Character.isDigit(string.charAt(0))
```

Answer (score 3):

Hay varias formas de hacer lo que quieres. Quizá lo más sencillo sea usar `substring`, pues al parecer no interesa una conversión de tipos, sino solamente verificar que el primer carácter es `9` o no.

Te muestro un ejemplo, usando también un operador ternario, el cual puede ser muy útil para estos casos, ayudando a simplificar código.

```
    String palabra = "9394";
    String laPrimera=palabra.substring(0, 1);
    String esNueve=(palabra != null && laPrimera.equals("9")) ? "Es nueve: " : "No es nueve, es: ";
    System.out.println(esNueve+laPrimera);
```

**Salida:**

```
Es nueve: 9
```

Si probásemos por ejemplo con este valor: `"1394"`, la salida sería:

```
No es nueve, es: 1
```